# member login and read own notes

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net

I have created a website where the user can become register and log in with their username / password when they log in, they can create his own notes + (here's my problem started> it must also be an option where they can read or see his own notes for ex on a second page.

I confused, maybe you guys can help me and I try also with different SQL statements and different Inner Join but,nothing happens on that page,where users can see his own notes after they finished with create his own notes.

My DB looks like this. 2 table. tblUser (fldID, fldusername, fldpassword) and tblNote (fldID, fldnotes)

My Code-behind and SQL statements look like this:

```
    Code-behind: Createnotes.aspx

    protected void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    getContent objNote = new getContent();
    objNote._Note = txtText.Text;
    objNote._IDnote = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]);
    objNote.AddNotes();

    litSvar.Text = "You have now create a Notes";
    Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "5; URL=Createnote.aspx");
}

    SQL statement : 
    public void AddNotes()
{
    string strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblNote (fldnote) VALUES(@Note)";
    SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand(strSQL);
    CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Note", _Note);
    CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDnote", _IDnote);

    objData.ModifyData(CMD);
}
 ................

    Code-behind: Usernotes.aspx
    if (Session["UserId"] != null)
    {
        objdinnote._IDnote = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]);
        DataTable dtnotes =    objdinnote.getNotesbyID(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]));
        foreach (DataRow notes in dtnotes.Rows)
        {
            litSvar.Text += notes["fldnote"];
        }
       }

    SQL statement:
     public DataTable getNotesbyID(int _Id)
     {
    string strSQL = ("select tblLogin.*, tblNote.fldnote from tblLogin INNER  JOIN tblNote ON tblLogin.fldID = tblNote.fldIDnote where tblLogin.fldID = @ID");
    SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand(strSQL);
    CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", _Id);
    return objData.GetData(CMD);
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is why i can't see or users can't see they  own notes or when they create notes is show nothing on page ,if you understand what i mean !

Comment: Please edit your question and remove all that bold style. You should also indent your code accordingly.

Comment: done, i just edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to join it with login if you know the field you can directly pass it to tblnote and get related notes

```
select fldnote from tblNote where  fldID= @ID
```

Comment: try to execute it directly on database then you can confirm result set